# Proof of the existence of $\sqrt 2$ using intermediate value theorem and generalizations

Tags: calculus

I want to prove the existence of $\sqrt 2$, i.e., the equation $x^2=2$ has a real solution. I did in this way:

> Let's define $f(x)=x^2-2$, since $f(0)=-2<0$ and $f(2)=2>0$, there is
>    a solution for the equation $x^2-2$, and the statement is proved.

My questions are:

1. Is my reasoning right?
2. What is the best generalization I can have using this argument? For example using the same reasoning if $a>1$ I can prove the existence of a number $x$ such that $x^2=a$. What about the n-root for any $a$?

Comment: That's correct. The result follows because $f(x) = x^2 -2$ is a continuous function.

Comment: You need the continuity of $f$, which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: To question (2), you absolutely can generalize to the $n$th root in the way you'd imagine

Comment: for (2), there are several iterative methods https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Comment: @eepperly16 are you sure? I'm having troubles to prove in the case $a<0$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} x^n - a = \pm \infty$. So for sufficiently large positive $x$, $x^n - a > 0$ and for sufficiently large negative $x$, $x^n - a < 0$. (This is just intuition, but you should be able to develop it into a full proof.)

Comment: @eepperly16 yesss, of course. I forgot this strategy. thank you very much